# Node-JS and Heroku, Having issues using require with an external JS file in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have an app which is running completely fine in my local development environment however when I transferred over to Heroku I get the following error:

```
2017-08-19T20:03:22.037036+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 
'/app/da/MongoDbConnector'
2017-08-19T20:03:22.037037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-08-19T20:03:22.037038+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(module.js:417:25)
2017-08-19T20:03:22.037038+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require 
(module.js:497:17)
```

This is my folder structure in my app:

[folder-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZOQG.png)

This is my Require

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var appRootDir = require('app-root-dir').get();
var MongoDbConnector = require(__dirname + '/../da/MongoDbConnector');
var md = new MongoDbConnector();
```

The MongoDBConnector is an external JS file which contains a class which has been exported using module.exports.

Comment: In which file are you importing `MongoDbConnector`, is it app.js in your folder structure?

Comment: It is in a file called uni.js which is located in the routes folder

Comment: why don't you just try `../da/MongoDbConnector`?

Comment: I did, it works on my local dev environment but in heroku i get the same error with that path

Comment: Finally found the issue it was firstly with the file name and not including the directory to express but thank you for your help Raghav.